# Fitnesse SLIM Query Table - Stopping empty cells from failing?

Tags: java, testing, fitnesse

I've got a large set of Fitnesse (For Java - v20090513) tests which are executed against a SLIM Query table.

To help with the testing (explain why we're getting certain results) I've added a new column to the end of the table. The idea is that the cells for that column would be empty (||) as they're not required to be tested against, it's just for informational purposes.

The problem with this is that Fitnesse causes every one of those cells to fail because the returned data is different to the data entered (which was nothing).

Is there a way to make Fitnesse ignore this column, or just make it pass? Ideally I don't want to change much of the fixture code which is being called. I understand I could use a table of type table and just match things up myself, but that's an hour or 2 of work which I can't really afford to do.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What is being returned? Is it just null? Could you change it to return a empty string? Can you explain why the property cannot return the same thing that's expected?

Comment: The returned cell contains a populated String with information useful to the tester. The whole problem is that it would be a very long and arduous task to go through and enter the correct data in the cells to match what is returned. I want to just display what gets returned, rather than it being tested against (so it doesn't fail each time).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a table fixure, you'll have to modify your fixture code so that if the column header is "Comment", the cells value is set to "ignore" in the ArrayList that is returned from the doTable function.

Comment: It isn't a table fixture, its Query fixture

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the empty cells aren't being ignored by Fitnesse [as they're supposed to](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.QueryTable); sounds like a bug to me.  Anyway, you may be able to work around it by putting `=~/.*/` in that column, i.e. a regexp that matches anything. (See [value comparisons](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ValueComparisons))